# Webpack 4 - HTML partials

Tags: html, webpack, gulp, partials

I'm working on Webpack/Gulp enviroment, and I wanna add function to include HTML partials like header and footer inside other page views.

The best solution for this will be like in PHP, include file and it's fine.
I used **html-webpack-plugin, html-loader and gulp-file-include** but this not working for me **or** this build one file from this partials and on development mode on local server i can't look to results because this partial before build not working.

Someone maybe have a solution or think for this?